# Delphi code sample for fingerprint recognition

Tags: delphi, fingerprint, biometrics

Do you know where can I find a  Delphi code sample for fingerprint recognition from an image file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know too much about biometrics image recognition, but you would have better luck looking for C or C++ code, and port it over to Delphi. See [Free Fingerprint Imaging Software](http://ffpis.sourceforge.net/) and [Fingerprint Verification System](http://fvs.sourceforge.net/) for starters. The first site contains useful links.

Comment: Your first link is wrong, it doesn't exist

Comment: @mm2010, what doesn't exist? I can follow the link fine.

Comment: Please share you findings, did you found something relevant or even get down to develop in the negative ?